# UWP deployable package doesnot consume WebAPI on other device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, owin

I am working on Xamarin Forms - UWP.
This is an offline project.
I am consuming the WebAPI hosted on the localhost(127.0.0.1):8080, on IIS Express. After packaging the application, it works fine on my machine. But, when I deploy the same package(run with powershell) on the other device, it doesn't consume it. Eventhough I have hosted the webAPI on that machine too at the same port.

It launches the app on other device but doesn't perform any webapi task.

I have tried using OWIN to self host the service locally but same output.

I appreciate any help on this!
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried that your API is "online" with Postman or Insomnia (for example)?

Comment: do you still have a problem? I don't see you reply on question.

Comment: Apologize for the late reply. Got it solved. It was because of the test certificate that was issued while creating a package.